# Not able to upload large files via plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, jquery-file-upload

The problem is from word-press admin panel, I can upload up to 100mb file. without any problem. But when  i am uploading it via simple script in plugin. Even 1 mb file its showing 413 "

> Request Entity Too Large

I know this is server side error, But my question is How word-press can able to upload large file via ajax and my script don't?
I am using this plugin for upload
 http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-file-upload/full_screen_preview/9254506
I have tried every thing like
In PHP Code
    ini_set('max_execution_time', "3600");
    ini_set('memory_limit', "99M");
    ini_set('post_max_size', '3000M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize','3000M');
    ini_set('max_input_time','3600');
    ini_set('client_max_body_size','200M');

In .htaccess file

```
LimitRequestBody 1024000
```

But i am not able to figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to amend your servers `php.ini` file.

The code you put in your answer included part of the answer which was messing up which is the `memory_limit`.

Try this:

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
max_execution_time = 3000
```

This allows for files up to 256Mb and will allow for up to 5 minutes of execution which can cause problems if you have a slow internet speed.

Amend it to whatever you think the absolute maximum file size will be.